# What is the file size upload limit for SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, file-upload, file

Is 50 MB the max file size upload limit for SharePoint Online site collection?

We have a business premium account in Office 365. We are Getting error trying to upload 48 MB files. Is there any way to change file size to allow me to upload a file more than 100 MB in size?

Answer (score 7):

**What is the file size upload limit for SharePoint online?**

the File upload limit for SharePoint Online in Office 365 Business Essentials and Office 365 Business Premium is **10 GB** per file and file attachment is **250Mb**.

> Note: In classic mode, upload methods other than drag and drop have a 2 GB
>   limit.

For more details check [Limits for SharePoint Online in Office 365 Business Essentials and Office 365 Business Premium](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Online-software-boundaries-and-limits-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498)

**Is there any way to change file size to allow me to upload a file?**

You can't change these settings in SharePoint online.You can change the file size upload limit in an on-premises environment, but it's not possible in SharePoint Online because it's a shared setting for all the tenants.

**We are Getting error trying to upload 48 MB files.**

I don't think you have got an error due to the file size, the 48Mb is not reached to the supported size limit. Moreover, you should be able to upload a file from the browser with a size up to 10 GB as I mentioned above.

So should you please tell us

1. What's the type of your error specifically?!,
2. Are you trying to upload the file from SharePoint or another third party program or programmatically? if yes kindly [check increasing file size limit for Sharepoint online for uploading files through SharePoint web service](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/9a4a8fd1-a6a6-40f1-a51e-d52784dba4fa/increazing-file-size-limit-for-sharepoint-2013-online-for-uploading-files-through-sharepoint-web?forum=sharepointgeneral)

Comment: The File upload limit for **[SharePoint 2019 and SharePoint Online is now 15GB](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sharepoint-2019-limitations/)**

Comment: January 2022 and it's 250GB now. Looks like it had been 100GB for a while and they increased it last year (Jan 2021) to 250GB.

Answer (score 2):

**FEATURE   DESCRIPTION**

File upload limit   10 GB - 1 byte (10,737,418,239 bytes) per file.

In **classic mode**, upload methods other than drag and drop have a 2 GB limit.

**File attachment size limit    250 MB**

Answer (score 2):

In the latest update (currently August 2017), file size limit has been increased to 15GB instead of 10GB. File attachment size limit keeps beeing 250 MB.

[SharePoint Online limits in February 3rd of 2018](https://web.archive.org/web/20180203170523/https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sharepoint-online-limits-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score 1):

As of 2020.05.22

15 GB

[SharePoint limits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits)

Comment: 100 GB as of 2020.08.04!

Comment: now (2022) looks like it's 250GB!

Answer (score 0):

A little late... but I think this may be related to the default file limit set by the WebDAV client.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2668751/you-cannot-download-more-than-50-mb-or-upload-large-files-when-the-upl