# Have file size is limited to 50MB to upload in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

In SharePoint online i am trying to upload a file of 50Mb in to the list.
but it is througing an error  as shown below.
i am able to upload the files upto 40mb and but for 50mb it is throwing an error.

Is there any chance to increase the limitation to more than 100mb?

Comment: Check this: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/211605/what-is-the-file-size-upload-limit-for-sharepoint-online

Comment: What error message did you get? Does this issue occur all libraries and all site collections?

Answer (score 2):

We can upload up to 15 GB file to SharePoint online and files attached to list items can be up to 250 MB in size.

You are trying to upload 50 MB, so it's not related to any file size issue. You can check the size limitations [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180203170523/https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sharepoint-online-limits-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

So, can you please check once the issue related to any other things. 
Hope this helps to you.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.
It was fixed by increasing the file size in the following registry subkey

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters\FileSizeLimitInBytes

Read other possible solutions here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2668751/you-cannot-download-more-than-50-mb-or-upload-large-files-when-the-upl

Adrian

Answer (score 0):

We usually faced something similar with users across the world. The error shows a message that could be related with some limits or boundaries of SharePoint but it doesn't. In our case, the error is that those users don't have a good network connection so they are not able to upload files so big, a network related issue.
The solution applied is tell them upload a bunch of files or one file with less size.